# Spring boot run script if spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto is not "update"?

Tags: spring-boot

If I set the application.properties, it gets error whenever it loads

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/init.dml/TB_FR_LANGUAGE_INFO_INITDATA.sql,classpath:/init.dml/TB_FR_MESSAGE_INFO_INITDATA.sql
```

How can I spring boot run the initial script only when the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto is create-drop or create?

**update**

How can I avoid the initial data insert script when it added once in the past?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of resource class path resource [init.dml/TB_FR_LANGUAGE_INFO_INITDATA.sql]: INSERT INTO TB_FR_LANGUAGE_INFO ( LANGUAGE_SQ, LANGUAGE_ID, LANGUAGE_NM, USE_YN, ORDER_NO, CREATE_DT, CREATE_USR_ID) VALUES ('LAN_000001','KO', 'Korean', 'Y' , 0, NOW(),'superadmin'); nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'LAN_000001' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:565)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:531)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:697)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:670)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
    ... 120 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of resource class path resource [init.dml/TB_FR_LANGUAGE_INFO_INITDATA.sql]: INSERT INTO TB_FR_LANGUAGE_INFO ( LANGUAGE_SQ, LANGUAGE_ID, LANGUAGE_NM, USE_YN, ORDER_NO, CREATE_DT, CREATE_USR_ID) VALUES ('LAN_000001','KO', 'Korean', 'Y' , 0, NOW(),'superadmin'); nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'LAN_000001' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:472)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:229)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runDataScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializer.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializer.java:46)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1719)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:113)
    ... 130 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'LAN_000001' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:848)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:742)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:457)
    ... 143 more
```

Comment: Pls share the error stacktrace for more info.

Comment: @Avis This configuration has nothing to do with generating the error. But  spring boot  try executing the script where I set the properties even if It has already inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hibernate ddl-auto which you using is as its name suggest applies only for DDLs i.e. schema definitions. To see actual code check this hibernate file :-

hibernate-orm/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/SettingsFactory.java

```
String autoSchemaExport = properties.getProperty( AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO );
if ( "validate".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) {
    settings.setAutoValidateSchema( true );
}
else if ( "update".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) {
    settings.setAutoUpdateSchema( true );
}
else if ( "create".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) {
    settings.setAutoCreateSchema( true );
}
else if ( "create-drop".equals( autoSchemaExport ) ) {
    settings.setAutoCreateSchema( true );
    settings.setAutoDropSchema( true );
}
else if ( !StringHelper.isEmpty( autoSchemaExport ) ) {
    LOG.warn( "Unrecognized value for \"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto\": " + autoSchemaExport );
}
```

Hibernate doesnt do any validation on data inserted/present on these tables and which actually you wanted to have. A way around for your problem is to have your inserts in following form where it checks if data not present then only insert :-

```
INSERT INTO TB_FR_LANGUAGE_INFO ( LANGUAGE_SQ, LANGUAGE_ID, LANGUAGE_NM, USE_YN, ORDER_NO, CREATE_DT, CREATE_USR_ID) 
    VALUES ('LAN_000001','KO', 'Korean', 'Y' , 0, NOW(),'superadmin') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (select LANGUAGE_SQ from TB_FR_LANGUAGE_INFO where LANGUAGE_SQ = 'LAN_000001');
```

Comment: it didn't work. even if I set the value of the property "validate", it didn't work and got the integrityconstraint violation exeception.

Comment: Pls add full stacktrace so i can see the point from where it started failing in Spring.

Comment: Updated again. I hope you can solve this :) I am expecting.

Comment: I will try :). Can you confirm once what type of script statement you have on both script files. My understanding is first script is having DDL while second is inserting some config data on those tables.

Comment: Absolutely, I wrote two scripts. but there are many files as the value of this property. But every scripts constitutes only insert scripts

Comment: I got your case & updated my answer above. Pls check & close.